# Trying to understand schematics of a microcontroller (TM4C123GXL)

Tags: microcontroller, led, schematics

I have a `TM4C123GXL` microcontroller with a hwllo-world app. that makes some LEDs to blink.

I have done this 'hello-world' by following a tutorial, but now I want to understand the schematics behind this (in other words, how I would found how to make the LEDs to blink if I hadn't a tutorial).

From the [microcontroller user guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu296/spmu296.pdf) (schematics part), I have got this image:

[image]

From that image, I can deduce that it's `PF1` (1 for red, 2 and 3 for blue and green respectively) the GPIO connected to the LED.

Now from this image:

[image]

I can deduce that I need to supply power to the `VBUS` pin, so when I write a `1` in the proper register's bit (in this case, `LED_R`), that will turn the BJT on, which will close the cirtuit from `VBUS` to ground, which will make the LED to shine.

**My first question is if my reasoning above is correct.**

Apart from that, I don't understand very well the `Input/Output BUS` symbol in this schema. I have googled it, and I have found the following:

[image]

According to that description, the first schema is correct, since the `input buses` at the end of the PF1,2,3 lines are input buses (they receive the info. from `PF1, 2, 3`).

As far as I understand, those buses should be drawn as output buses in the second schema, but they are input buses as well (according to the symbol reference above). I don't mind if the symbol is exactly as it should be, I just want to be sure that I have understood it correctly: The BJTs schema states that if you write a `1` in `LED_R`, you enable the BJT thus turning the LEDs on. Is this correct?

Comment: VBUS is (probably) not something *you* supply power to. It should be the power coming from somewhere else. Search for VBUS, it will probably be connected to the power supply (USB?)

Comment: Those arrow-like symbols are off-page connectors - they indicate that wire connects to a wire with the same name on another page of the schematic.  The direction of the arrow doesn't necessarily indicate the direction of signal flow.

Comment: @user253751 you are right, usually the microcontroller should be powered through USB. However, in the project I'm doing the microcontroller should be powered with a battery. I use a voltage regulator to transform 9V to 3.3V and I connect it directly to the VBUS PIN. Is this dangerous? How did you figure out that VBUS was powered by the USB?

Comment: I guessed, because USB power is usually called VBUS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning for the transistor circuit is correct.

The input and output symbols are not universal. Sometimes they indicate signal direction, sometimes not. A good schematic (for westerners at least) should have inputs on the left side and outputs on the right side (western people think left to right).

What is more universal is that connections with identical names are connected to each other within multiple schematic sheets. Sometimes the connections are within the same page, but this should be avoided IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> The BJTs schema states that if you write a 1 in LED_R, you enable the
>   BJT thus turning the LEDs on. Is this correct?

### Yes.

**The second part:**

- The symbols are called off page connectors.
- Normally they are sued when you can not complete the drawing of that particular net in the same page.
- The shape of the symbol depends on whether t shape is near the source or the destination of the signal.
- Since the MCU is *sending* the signals, the shape roses the output arrow ones (output bus line).
- The shape takes the input bus line near the BJT becausehe BJT it is a input signal.
- There are also bi directional bud lines (for example: data line of a RAM ).

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct.  The control of the LEDs should work as you describe.

The Bus terminals that you describe are NOT actually bus terminals.  Instead they are Logical Connections.  They are used to indicate that a signal is carried to a different sheet / page / diagram within the schematic.  In this form a 'box with a pointy end' (commonly called an off sheet connector) it is common to indicate the direction of signal flow away from the arrow (the pointy end).

```
------>      
   or         would be a wires with a signal leaving the sheet
<------


>------
   or        would be a wire with a signal entering the sheet
------<
```

The schematics do show a bus as well.  The very first schematic contains two buses named GPIO and DEBUG/VCOM.  The bus itself is shown as a thicker line.  The GPIO bus shows multiple nets entering (or leaving) the bus with their individual names next to the entry (or exit point)

```
|
|   
|\_______NET
|
|
BUS
```